# Is this possible to use a front-end JS Framework on the server side with Node.JS to create a Web service for content delivery?

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server, serverside-javascript, node-canvas

I have a complete project made with Playcanvas (a JS GameEngine Framework) that uses the HTML canvas tag.
This project can also generate images in different format (base64, dataUrl, blob, jpeg).

I want to put this project on the server side to create a new Web service that can deliver images, generated from that Playcanvas project.

So, is this possible to use a functional code from the client-side and put it on the server-side with Node.JS? 
I know some works like [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) that achieve a similar goal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use puppeteer(headless chrome) to get the full control of a browser on the server side. You can then render the images on the server in required format and can export to the front end.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: Interesting, I will check that project for sure.